# How to check Webmethod version on linux?

Tags: linux, webmethods

Hi I need to check the version of the running Webmethods, but I don't have access to the console. Can anyone let me know how I cant check the version of the Webmethods on linux?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Look for "application.version=..." inside [IS]/bin/ini.cnf

Comment: For 9.X version you'll find this file in your instance bin dir. By default you use default instance: .../IntegrationServer/instances/default/bin/ini.cnf

Answer (score 0):

U can also check through running system info built in service in developer